# jQuery file not being retrieved from server

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

For some reason my html file's request for my jquery.js file fails, however when I enter that exact url into a new tab in the browser, I get the exact jquery.js file I am trying to get when the website loads.

My code is as such:

```
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
```

and my website [is here](http://ilanshomekitchen.x10.mx/). If you append jquery.js to the root, you will see the exact file.

Can anyone explain why the file isn't properly retrieved when the website loads?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It is retrieved successfully for me.

Comment: What browser are you using? If you are using firefox, try to show the source code and fllow the link of the javascript code to see if your path is correct. Here it is ok too.

Comment: It seems to be working fine ... please add some more details ... did you try looking at the Net panel in Firebug (for Firefox)

Comment: FF is loading `jquery.js` file, but the Chrome is not. Though I can open that file by direct link in Chrome.

Comment: I am using chrome dev tools on a guest's computer, so I don't have FF.

Comment: Seems to have something to do with this: http://ilanshomekitchen.x10.mx/appcache.appcache

Comment: The first time I opened it in Chrome worked fine, the second time onwards which seem to use the stored files for offline usage do not fetch the jQuery library.

Answer (score 4):

At the beginning of your HTML file is this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html manifest="appcache.appcache">
```

The `appcache.appcache` refers to the file [appcache.appcache](http://ilanshomekitchen.x10.mx/appcache.appcache) whose content is:

```
CACHE MANIFEST
# V1.65 1-18-2013 10:15 PM

# cache

index.html
about.html
services.html
contact.html
css/signika.css
css/mq.css
css/index.css
css/about.css
css/services.css
css/contact.css
assets/signika_400.woff
assets/signika_600.woff
js/html5.js
js/index.js
js/mq.js
js/services.js
mail.php
images/chicken.png
images/salad.png
images/soup.png
images/steak.png
images/wontons.png
```

As you can see `jQuery.js` is not there. I suggest you to add `js/jQuery.js` into a new line and try again.

---

I figured this out by:

- Running [the Fiddler software](http://www.fiddler2.com/) side by side with Chrome (on Windows).
- Loading your website in Chrome with Developer Tools (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> on Windows, <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Option ⌥</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> on Mac), then go to the Network tab.

Then I see that Chrome loads `appcache.appcache` from the second time onwards and there's an error when loading `jQuery.js`.

---

The `manifest` attribute refers to the **HTML5 cache manifest file**.

Tutorial:

- http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/

More references:

- http://caniuse.com/#search=manifest (browser compatibility)
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_manifest_in_HTML5 (wiki)
- https://www.google.com/search?q=html5+manifest

Comment: +1 ... I wonder if this would count as a bug in Chrome? because FF and other browsers can handle this situation ... and there is no simple way to identify this problem in Chrome's debugger

Comment: js, the problem is if the file isn't declared, nothing happens, you need to specifically declare to retrieve the file under the # network section... :) which I forgot to do.

Answer (score 0):

It's probable that the HTML file containing the script header in question is not in the "root" but perhaps in the same JS folder or somewhere else.

So technically this should work:

```
<script src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
```

Just keep in mind that this path is relative.

Comment: You can view the file structure in chrome or firefox by looking at the source paths...and if it works in FF, it should work in chrome.